# best strategy apply a hot fix to two different release versions, that have version tags and their own changelogs

Tags: git, version-control

The background:

The background context is that two release branches can exist at once. One will be in 'prod' environment and one in 'alpha'.

Let's say the two branches are release/1.1.0 (which is in prod) and release/1.2.0 (which is in alpha). release/1.1.0 is still completely in the history of release/1.2.0. In fact, let's say release/1.2.0 is just one additional feature commit ahead of release/1.1.0. The tip of release/1.1.0 is commit 123abc and the tip of release/1.2.0 is 456def,

A semantic versioning tool is used that can bump the version by traversing the commits and bumping based on conventional commit formats (feat/fix/etc...).  The tool updates the changelog and applies a tag to the commit at the tip of the branch.

Right now, the tip of release/1.1.0 has been tagged v1.1.0 and the tip of release/1.2.0 has been tagged v1.2.0.

The problem:

An error is detected in v1.1.0 while it is running in prod. To fix the issue, a hotfix branch is created off of release/1.1.0, the code is fixed and that branch is merged into release/1.1.0 and release/1.2.0 (and also the dev branch). The versioning tool is run on both branches, and their version have changes to v1.1.1 and v1.2.0.  Nothing has 'broken' *yet*...but I think those steps I just described are wrong and set us up for what I am about to describe in the paragraph below. The branches have now diverged - they both have the same commits, but the fix order is wrong. What I mean is release/1.2.0 does not have a version 1.1.1 in it's history. Also, the branch names are still release/1.1.0 and release/1.2.0 even though those are no longer their versions, which seems wrong.

Now, lets' say, another error is detected in prod. So we make another hotfix branch off of release/1.1.0. We then merge that in to release/1.1.0 and release/1.2.0. Now we have problem. First off, there are merge conflicts between the changelogs, and release/1.2.0 will look like it went from version 1.2.0 to 1.2.1 to 1.1.1 because the hotfix branch contains the commit that has been tagged as 1.1.1. It's a mess.

Is there a better way to apply the fix to both releases without destroying the version history and have changelog merge hell? I had thought of rebasing release/1.2.0 onto the hotfix branch. But I think there are problems with that... maybe I would first have to destroy all version tags that are > 1.1.1 and also undo the changelog commits before rebasing, and then rerun the version tool after rebasing

Another thought is to checkout the dev branch at the commit where release/1.1.0 was branched off. Write a test and fix the code, then commit that (I will refer to this commit as the fix_commit in the next lines). Rebase the rest of dev back on to the fix_commit, so that dev now has that commit in its history. Then, branch off a new release/1.1.1 at the fix_commit. Then, branch off a new release/1.2.0 from the same commit that is was originally branched off from. What is odd here is that release/1.2.0 would still be 1.2.0 because the fix is in it's history before the feat commit that causes the bump from 1.1.x -> 1.2.0. Maybe that is good? I like this idea because it is closer to trunk-based dev in that work is always done on the dev branch

Another thought: fix release/1.1.0 directly, no hotfix branch, just commit the fix and increment the version (if I want, I could then branch off release/1.1.1 and deploy that, and delete release/1.1.0). Then cherry pick the commit to release/1.2.0, and increment the version to 1.2.1. (and then also apply the cherry picked commit to dev).

What is the best strategy?

More background:
We are moving to trunk based dev. I understand, in trunk based dev, you only ever have one release live. If an issue is detected, your write a test for it on the dev and then make a new release. You are never branching off of a release, for a hot fix, and the merging that back into your release and dev.

However, we have alpha and prod environments and we usually have one version in prod and a version that is further ahead in alpha. So, we can not follow the pattern of only every having one release. I suspect a suggestion would be to not use two releases to differentiate between what is in prod and alpha and to, instead, use feature flags. The flags would be on in alpha and off in prod (and the flag could be set by an environment variable). That way, we really only have one release.  That could be great also, but that would require some other changes in our dev process.

Comment: Consider the [Gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), it is made to handle multiple versions and hotfixes.

Comment: @Schwern We do want to move towards trunk based; however, you are correct, we should consider the gitflow workflow, maybe it is a better fit. Thank you.

Comment: @Schwern ok, I see... at first I thought gitflow would not work either, but I now understand that what is deployed in alpha would still need to be on its release branch. Only merge into main when ready to deploy prod, and only every tag version on main. This keeps the version history clean.  This is actually close to what we currently are doing (not what is described in the post)

Comment: Is this a typo: "Let's say the two branches are release/1.1.0 (which is in prod) and release/1.2.0 (which is in prod)." (The sentence before that suggest one would be in prod and the other in alpha.)

Comment: @TTT you are correct, just fixed. Thank you!

Comment: This might be the answer you're looking for, and if so I can write it up. The summary is: you could rename your release branches to not include the 3rd number so that subsequent builds can be on the same branch, e.g. `release/1.1`. After creating the hotfix for tag "1.1.1" on `release/1.1`, merge `release/1.1` into `release/1.2`. If you've already generated the changelog on `release/1.2` you'll have a conflict, so manually resolve it and update the log with the correct order. Then merge `release/1.2` down to `dev` and resolve. (The idea is to favor merge over cherry-pick whenever possible.)

Comment: I believe this pretty much discusses your use-case: https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/branch-for-release/

Comment: @taleodor yes thank you! This seems to be the solution.